# Using a subclassed PFObject in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I've subclassed `PFObject` like so:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

class Post: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

    class func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "Post"
    }

}
```

Registering it in AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
Post.registerSubclass()
```

I'm trying to use that class within my tableView:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(postCellReuseIdentifier) as? PostCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = PostCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: postCellReuseIdentifier)
    }
    if let postCell = cell {
        // assign post to the cell
        postCell.post = object as! Post?
        // setup delegate
        postCell.delegate = self
        return postCell
    }

    return nil
}
```

I need to cast object as Post, but can't figure out how. I currently get this error:

> Could not cast value of type 'PFObject' (0x10c856ef8) to 'MyApp.Post' (0x10c855670).

Comment: Have you used `registerSubclass`?

Comment: Yes and I've updated my question to show registration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working. The following is required to subclass:

Add this to your bridging header:

```
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>
```

Create your class:

```
class MyClass: PFObject, PFSubclassing {

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "MyParseClass"
    }

}
```

Important: Make sure the class name returned in `parseClassName()` exactly matches the name of the class you created on Parse.com.

Register the subclass in AppDelegate:application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
MyClass.registerSubclass()
```

You should now be able to cast a PFObject to your class.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure that your are subclassing a `PFObject` correctly by registering the instance. Also the downcast you are trying is impossible. You cannot downcast an instance of a base class to an instance of a derived class unless it is simply a derived instance stored as a base class.

Comment: I've edited my question to show the registration I'm using. How do I use a subclassed object in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath which takes a pfobject?

Comment: Probably by not subclassing a PFObject. Make the Post class to be a wrapper around a PFObject by keeping a PFObject property which could be initialise via a constructor. Then you can try doing something like `postCell.post = Post(object)` instead